# Making threaded NSURLConnections

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsurlconnection

I have a lot of connections going when my app starts, so I wanna put them on background threads so I can make new connections other than the starting connections before they all complete.

Below, `threadedRequest:` is a method that's starting a NSURLConnection, but when I call `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` in the `if` clause, the connection starts, but never finishes.  The `else` clause works fine and returns data from the connection

```
if (background)
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(threadedRequest:) withObject: args];
}
else
{
    [self performSelector: @selector(threadedRequest:) onThread: [NSThread mainThread] withObject: args waitUntilDone: NO];
}
```

Comment: NSURLConnection already has an async interface. In other words, Apple wrote the threading code for you. Are you using it?

Comment: Noo I don't think so. Is it with `sendAsynchronousRequest:`?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest to use. You can also use -initWithRequest:delegate: and implement the delegate callbacks.

Comment: That's what I was doing, but when I put on a new request it waited for the rest to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform `NSURLConnection` in the background, you must be sensitive to special conditions that apply to [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods in background threads. You have several options:

1. Use one of the non-delegate alternatives. Given that you're performing this in the background, you could use [`sendSynchronousRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI), or if just requesting data from a simple URL, you could use `NSData` class method [`dataWithURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL%3aoptions%3aerror%3a).
2. If you really need the delegate version (because you need progress updates via [`didReceiveData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011348-CH1-SW4) or because you need one of the [`NSURLConnectDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods for authentication or the like, you have a couple of basic options:

   - You can create a `NSOperationQueue` and set the delegate queue for the connection. For example, rather than:

     ```
     - (void)startConnection:(NSURL *)url
     {
         NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
         [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
     }
     ```

     You could do:

     ```
     - (void)startConnection:(NSURL *)url
     {
         NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
         NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
         [connection setDelegateQueue:self.connectionDelegateQueue];
         [connection start];
     }
     ```
   - Alternatively, you could do what [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) does (see [`AFURLConnectionOperation.m`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m), for sample implementation):

     - Create a dedicated `NSThread` for the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` calls;
     - Start a `NSRunLoop` on that thread;
     - Use the same `startImmediately:NO` rendition of the `NSURLConnection` init method as above; and
     - Use the `scheduleInRunLoop` option for the `NSURLConnection` before you `start` it.
   - Or, easiest, you could just use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Two observations:

1. I might be inclined to use operation or dispatch queues instead of `performSelectorInBackground`. See [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/).
2. By the way, you should be aware that there is a limit as to how many concurrent `NSURLConnection` requests iOS can perform simultaneously (it's 5 or 6, I believe). Thus, if you initiate a dozen background requests and then initiate a "foreground" request, the "foreground" request may *not* start immediately. You may want to limit how many background requests that can operate concurrently if you want to avoid this potential problem.

   Personally, when I want to constrain the number of network requests, I add my background requests to a `NSOperationQueue` and set the number of [maximum concurrent operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-borderType) (e.g. I generally use 4), enjoying the benefits of concurrent operations, while not trying to perform more simultaneous connections than iOS will permit. By the way, when availing yourself of operation queue's `maxConcurrentOperations` feature, you have to make sure that the requests are synchronous (or wrap the asynchronous connection in a custom `NSOperation` that won't terminate until the connection is done or fails).

Comment: Thanks a lot for really explaining in so much detail how this works :)